# For a given IDL and account name, is there a lib (anchor or other) or function that finds for each account struct key, the offset where it begins?

Tags: anchor, idl, anchor-program-idl

So I'm having trouble finding the offset for some account keys of programs that have an IDL and would like to get some help on this. For example in this program

https://solscan.io/account/dRiftyHA39MWEi3m9aunc5MzRF1JYuBsbn6VPcn33UH#anchorProgramIDL

I would like for this account:

[image: Account struct]

To know the offset where the key "unrealizedPnlMaxImbalance" begins.

Thank you in advance, for any help given

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit annoying, but if you want the offset, the easiest option is to just count up all the bytes to get to the field that you care about.  In your case, we can count all the way `unrealizedPnlMaxImbalance`:

- `pubkey`: 32 bytes
- `amm`: this one's complicated since it's a big type called "AMM" and has many subtypes in it. You could go through by hand and count the number of bytes in all the fields, but I'm being lazy, sorry!
- `pnlPool`: `PoolBalance` which is 16 bytes for `scaledBalance`, 2 for `marketIndex`, and 6 for `padding`
- `name`: 32 bytes
- `insuranceClaim`: 5 ints, 8 bytes each
- `unrealizedPnlMaxImbalance`: made it!

I hope this will be a good first step, and apologies for my laziness for counting up the bytes in the `AMM` type. Best of luck!